# Terminate npm start with custom error if file is not present in repository

Tags: javascript, npm, terminal, console

Is it possible to interrupt/terminate the `npm start` process if a particular file is missing from your codebase?

I want to terminate the process if the file `dev-variables.js` is not present, preferably with a custom error along the lines of "You are missing the dev-variables.js file".

Answer (score 1):

Use `prestart` https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

```
"scripts": {
  "prestart": "scripts/check-dev-variables.js"
}
```

where `scripts/check-dev-variables.js` will throw an exception if file is not found